# Neo4j Import error: Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size

Tags: neo4j

Using Neo4j 2.3.1 Community Edition and trying to import about 19 million nodes using Neo4jImport.bat.

Unfortunately the import fails and Neo4j does not tell me which line number it was trying to read when it fail.

I am using the --stacktrace parameter, but all I get is the stack trace below.

Is there any other way to tease a line number out of the importer?

EDIT:

The CSV-file looks like this:

```
:ID(Item),id:int,name:string,:LABEL
1,1,"universe",Item
8,8,"happiness",Item
```

Its autogenerated, so the probability of a missing end-quote is rather small. Quotes in the data will be escaped with \ - there may be other special characters in there, but the file is utf8-encoded. Still the importer should be able to tell the line number in which it started to read the faulty data.

The command line:

"C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\Neo4jImport.bat" --input-encoding UTF8 --stacktrace  --into E:\data.graphdb --nodes items.csv

Import error: Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size 4194304
Caused by:Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size 4194304
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size 4194304
        at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.fillBufferIfWeHaveExhaustedIt(BufferedCharSeeker.java:267)
        at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.nextChar(BufferedCharSeeker.java:240)
        at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.seek(BufferedCharSeeker.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$AbstractDefaultFileHeaderParser.create(DataFactories.java:268)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(IteratorBatcherStep.java:45)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.InputIteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(InputIteratorBatcherStep.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)

Comment: Could you share a bit more detail about the size and structure of the CSV files you try to import ? And the command line you call?

Comment: Details shared. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case of a forgotten end quote. Are you running this with `--multiline-fields`? It's hard for the CSV parser to figure out whether a field has a forgotten end quote or not when multi-line fields, i.e. fields that span many lines, are in there.

So try running w/o `--multiline-fields` if you know that your values won't have line breaks.

Comment: I am running it without multiline-fields. And even if I were using multiline-fields the parser should still be able to tell on which line things started to go haywire ;)

Comment: Having the exception mention something about the start line of the problems sounds like a good addition.

Comment: Yes, please! That would make finding the problem so much easier.

Comment: Please check out 2.3.3, it should now include information about this, if you encounter it again.